# SQL query to filter results by two distinct columns

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
contracts

id   |   payer_user_id   |   receiver_user_id   |   amount
-----------------------------------------------------------
1    |   12              |   34                 |   12.03
2    |   12              |   34                 |   998
3    |   12              |   45                 |   123.12
4    |   34              |   23                 |   123.12
5    |   45              |   12                 |   34.1
6    |   18              |   12                 |   34
```

`payer_user_id` and `receiver_user_id` are both the foreign key references to the **user** table.

I want to fetch all the distinct id of the users from the **contracts** table that are associated with *user 12* in either way (as a payer or a receiver)

So, the result should be:

```
34
45
18
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union query:

```sql
SELECT payer_user_id FROM contracts WHERE receiver_user_id = 12
UNION
SELECT receiver_user_id FROM contracts WHERE payer_user_id = 12;
```

Each half of the above union query finds IDs on one side of the relationship with user 12.  Note that we don't even have to explicitly use `DISTINCT` here, because the union will remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CASE .. WHEN` and `IN` as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT case when payer_user_id <> 12 
                     then payer_user_id 
                     else receiver_user_id 
                end 
  FROM contracts 
 WHERE 12 IN (receiver_user_id,payer_user_id);
```